# If a surface has a differentiable Gauss map, then it has an orientation?

Tags: differential-topology, orientation

If a surface $S\subset R^3$ has a differentiable Gauss map $N:S\rightarrow S^2$, then $S$ has an orientation? How can I prove this statement? (Here, orientation is defined by a choice of equivalence class, specified by a choice of ordered basis;  a Gauss map is "a map $N:S\rightarrow S^2$, such that $T_xS=N(x)^\perp$")

Answer (score 0):

Orient $\mathbb{R}^3$ by some choice of basis. Given any other basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ we can say if it is positive or negative with respect to this orientation.

Let's suppose we have a Gauss map of our surface $S$. At each point $x\in S$ we can, using the oriention of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the choice of Gauss map $N$ define an orientation of basis of $T_xS$: We say a basis $e_1,e_2\in T_xS$ is a positive basis, if $(e_1,e_2)$ is a basis of $T_xS$ and $(e_1,e_2,N(x))$ is a positive basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: orientation is a choice of equivalence class, specified by a choice of ordered basis.

Comment: @oklabro: I've edited

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please be a little more specific? How does differentiability work here?

Comment: The gauss map is automatically differentiable if it is continuous and the surface is smooth. The continuity is necessary to make sure that the choice of orientation "varies continuously along the surface". Again I would want to ask you your definition of orientation. It can't just be that you orient each tangent space: this can always be done. Continuity has to be involved.

Comment: There is some proof that needs to be done here... But the way you did it doesn't seem to "prove" it.

Comment: What I proved was that a Gauss map (irrespective of its differentiability) orients each tangent space canonically. You will need to tell me what you mean with an orientation of a surface. Some continuity will be involved.

Comment: Suppose $B,B'$  are ordered bases and $P_{BB'}$ is the change of basis matrix. Then $B~B'$ defines the same orientation if $det(P_{BB'})>0$

Comment: Ok, but how do you define $\emph{continuous}$ family of orientations?